# Invoke ansible playbook in jenkins from different server

Tags: ansible, jenkins

I have two different servers. One is centos where my jenkins is located. Other one is Ubuntu. 
It's easy to invoke a playbook from centos in jenkins as the playbook and the jenkins are in same server.

But I have one playbook which is Ubuntu server. The problem is, how can I invoke this playbook in jenkins that's sitting on centos?

Help/Suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you for taking out your time in reading this question!

Answer (score 1):

Make the Centos machine your 'admin server', install Jenkins and Ansible core on it, and check out your plays from version control to that server.

Then set up all hosts to be managed by Ansible core.

Once that is done, you have Jenkins automate the running of plays.

One thing you should automate is to periodically pull changes from version control of your Ansible plays and Jenkins configs, and any resource files.

Comment: I did that and it gave me this error: FAILED | rc=1 >>
ERROR! the playbook: site.yml could not be foundnon-zero return code
FATAL: command execution failed